# Looking for guidance on a simple conditional

Tags: python

I'm looking for some guidance on where my logic went wrong on my answer to this question:

'Given 2 int values, return True if one is negative and one is positive. Except if the parameter "negative" is True, then return True only if both are negative.'

Here is my attempt.  I thought I was on the right track, where did I go wrong?

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
  if negative:
      if a < 0 and b < 0:
           return True
  elif ((a < 0 or b > 0) or (a > 0 or b < 0)):
      return True
  else:
      return False
```

this is the solution:

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
    if negative:
        return (a < 0 and b < 0)
    else:
        return ((a < 0 and b > 0) or (a > 0 and b < 0))
```

Comment: In the second conditional, the example you provided as your attempt ( which i am assuming is the first code snippet), you are using 'or' where you should be using 'and'.

Comment: There's a branch that doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Rawing - more precisely, there's a branch that implicitly returns `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with the `negative` branch:

```
if negative:
    if a < 0 and b < 0:
        return True
```

In case the `if a < 0 and b < 0` isn't True you don't return anything, but you should return `False`:

```
if negative:
    if a < 0 and b < 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

That can also be simplified because `a < 0 and b < 0` is already the result that should be returned so you can also use the less verbose:

```
if negative:
    return a < 0 and b < 0
```

---

Then there is a logic error in the second case:

```
elif ((a < 0 or b > 0) or (a > 0 or b < 0)):
```

That should trigger if `(a < 0)` **and** `(b > 0)` is True and likewise for the second parens. So it should be:

```
elif ((a < 0 and b > 0) or (a > 0 and b < 0)):
  return True
else:
  return False
```

Likewise you can use here the less verbose:

```
else:
    return ((a < 0 and b > 0) or (a > 0 and b < 0))
```

Comment: If a truthy value is passed in as `negative`, this function will give a logic error. OP said; "Except if the parameter `negative` is `True`", not "If the parameter `negative` evaluates to `True`"

Comment: @TomWyllie Given that the OP included the "solution" and it also just contained a `if negative:` I guess that meant "truthy" not "is True". However it would be easy to change it to a `if negative is True:` if required.

Answer (score 1):

Since @MSeifert explained your errors, here's an even less verbose version:

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
    return a * b < 0 if not negative else a < 0 and b < 0
```

Comment: What if `negative` is falsy? Such as an empty `string`, `list` or `set`.

Comment: @Tom Then you have bigger issues... you could check `if negative is False` but I wouldn't consider that Pythonic. All of other solutions also assume that you can use the truthiness of `negative`.

Comment: I disagree - *The Zen of Python* says explicitly that "Errors should never pass silently". At the very least, passing in `negative` should throw an error, and not be allowed to pass silently in defiance of the logic that OP presented, which was that "if the parameter "negative" is `True`".

Comment: Also, comparing singletons using `is`, such as `if negative is False`, is most certainly not un-pythonic. It is specifically suggested in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) - " beware of writing if x when you really mean if x is not None -- e.g. when testing whether a variable or argument that defaults to None was set to some other value. The other value might have a type (such as a container) that could be false in a boolean context!"

Comment: truthiness =/> `is True`; `bool('foo')` gives
`True`, 
`'foo' is True` gives
`False`

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure why you're raising this seemingly pedantic argument with my code, but you're entitled to your opinion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149046/discussion-between-tom-wyllie-and-jared-goguen).

Comment: @TomWyllie Duck typing is a fundamental principle in python. If someone passes a list or a string instead of a boolean, we don't care. They can be interpreted as a boolean, so it doesn't matter. It's not our responsibility to check if you've given us a boolean; it's your responsibility to pass a value with an appropriate truthiness.

Comment: @Rawing as I said to Jared this clearly doesn't matter in OP's use case, but I think it's important the distinction is made to somebody learning programming. My suggestion was that as OP had *specifically said* in his post "if the parameter `negative` is `True`", then a comparison should be made to the singleton, as requested. He placed no bounds and what else `negative` should be, and it seems that truthy values would defy the behaviour he outlined in his question.

Comment: @TomWyllie please stop. We get your point. It's not a valid issue, not with this question, nor in general, nor when teaching introductory Python. The only cases where it's an issue are listed in the section of PEP8 that you quoted.

Comment: Given that the same logic is also used in the solution that OP quoted, I'll concede that in this case you are all correct and it is a meaninglessly small detail.

Answer (score 1):

The comments have covered your semantic error (or vs and).

Stylistically, it's bad form to have code that says:

```
if condition:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

you should instead do:

```
return condition
```

note that there is absolutely no need to write the return value in parenthesis, i.e. this is better:

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
    if negative:
        return a < 0 and b < 0
    else:
        return a < 0 and b > 0 or a > 0 and b < 0
```

A case can be made to enclose the parameters to the `or` in the last line in parenthesis for readability, but since this is Python we can also do:

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
    if negative:
        return a < 0 > b
    else:
        return a < 0 < b  or  a > 0 > b
```

The last line is much better than a set of nested and/or clauses.

Now, if you want the shortest possible solution (assuming we're dealing with integers), then perhaps:

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
    return (a & b if negative else a ^ b) < 0
```

which relies on the binary representation of negative integers :-)